# match a regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex in php that matches statements like : `{{User:JYBot/count|700,000}}`

commnet : only the number 700,000 is variable and other are fixed.

I wrote this : `'/\{\{User:JYBot/count\|\d{1,10}\}\}/'` but it does not work properly, because of existence of `/` in it.this regex too does not work properly : `'/\{\{User:JYBot\/count\|\d{1,10}\}\}/'`

Please help me about it.
Regards

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not matching the comma also.

Comment: If everything else is fixed, why not use `substr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some little how-to. Take your string:

```
{{User:JYBot/count|700,000}}
```

Enclose the parts that should be matched verbatim into `\Q...\E`:

```
\Q{{User:JYBot/count|\E  ...  \Q}}\E
```

Now replace the dynamic part `700,000` with its pattern, e.g. `[\d,]{1,10}`:

```
\Q{{User:JYBot/count|\E[\d,]{1,10}\Q}}\E
```

Add the delimiters (there are more than `/`, take one *not* part of the string so far or something with parenthesis like `()`/`{}`or`[]` ) and you are done:

```
~\Q{{User:JYBot/count|\E[\d,]{1,10}\Q}}\E~
```

Comment: Thanks.it is very good.Thanks for your good instruction

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 /\{{2}User:JYBot\/count\|([0-9\,]+)\}{2}/is
```

You will, however, get the comma in the number, so you'll need to str_replace it away.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming the number is split with commas:

```
/\{\{User:JYBot\/count\|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\}\}/
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to escape your slashes or use different delimiters:

**escaping slashes:**

```
'/\{\{User:JYBot\/count\|\d{1,10}\}\}/'
```

**different delimiters:**

```
'~\{\{User:JYBot/count\|\d{1,10}\}\}~'
```

Comment: Half way through typing basically the same thing :)

Comment: Thanks.But it does not work properly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the `/` from the regular expression parser, which means that the parser needs to see a `\` before it.  However, the PHP string expresion `"\/"` is going to evaluate as `"/"` -- you escape the forward slash from PHP's string literal parser, and so the `\` character does not wind up being part of the final string.

In order get an actual `\` in the string, use two of them:

```
'/\{\{User:JYBot\\/count\|\d{1,10}\}\}/'
```

The regular expression parser will then see the `\/` sequence you intend.

Comment: Thanks.But it does not work properly.

Comment: @JavadYousefi You have more than one problem, apparently.  This is one of them, but there are others.